# Formula calculator in jQuery

Tags: jquery, formula

I'm attempting to finish a calculator which calculates values visa versa based on input.

When I'd like to calculate the PPM, I need the MGM3 and the Mol
When I'd like to calculate the MGM3, I need the PPM and the Mol

Now, the thing is that it's not working correctly. I'm still new to this kind of calculations. I hope someone could help me fix this.

**Above fixed**
Update: Only in firefox there occurs an error when using 3 numbers behind the dot. 
For example, fill in: 
*• mol: 30*
*• Mg/m3: 0,15*
After completion supplement the mg/m3 with several numbers and the outcome is invalid. How do I fix this?

```js
// formula for ppm =    mg/m3 * 24.45 / mol
// formula for mg/m3 =  ppm * mol / 24.45
 
 
 $('input.value').keyup(function(){
    var ppm = $('#ppm');
    var mgm3 = $('#mgm3');
    var mol = $('#mol');

    if( $('#ppm').val() != '') {
        $('#mgm3').attr('disabled', true);

        $(this).calculateMGM3;
    } else {
        $('#mgm3').attr('disabled', false);
    }

    if( $('#mgm3').val() != '') {
        $('#ppm').attr('disabled', true);

        $(this).calculatePPM; 
    } else {
        $('#ppm').attr('disabled', false);
    }

    function calculateMGM3() {
        var mol = $('#mol').val();
        var ppm = $('#ppm').val();
        var calcMGM3 = (( ppm * mol ) / 24.45 );
        $mgm3.val( calcMGM3 );
    }

    function calculatePPM() {
        var mol = $('#mol').val();
        var mgm3 = $('#mgm3').val();
        var calcPPM = (( mgm3 * 24.45 ) / mol );
        $ppm.val( calcPPM );
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="calc">
    <h1>MG/M³ - PPM Calculator</h1>
    <div class="gfield">
        <label>PPM</label>
        <input class="value" type="number" name="ppm" id="ppm">
    </div>
    <div class="gfield">
        <label>MG/M³</label>
        <input class="value" type="number" name="mgm3" id="mgm3">
    </div>
    <div class="gfield">
        <label>Molmassa</label>
        <input class="value" type="number" name="mol" id="mol">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: "Not working correctly" is not a good problem statement. Any errors? Incorrect results? Something else?

Comment: Look for [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). The values you get from the text inputs are strings... That is why your calculations fail.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, also check to see if you have 2 numbers, or if just one field has been filled. After that, call your functions with `calculateMGM3()` instead of `$(this).calculatePPM`

Comment: And in addition to *both* of those comments, you're never actually calling the `calculateXXX` method.

Comment: @Jamiec You're right, I'll edit the post. The problem is that I don't get any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient way, but this is what I accomplished. Now it seems to work like charm.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input#ppm').keyup(function(){
        if( $('#ppm').val() != '') {
            $('#mgm3').attr('disabled', true);
            calculateMGM3();
        } else {
            $('#mgm3').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    $('input#mgm3').keyup(function(){
        if( $('#mgm3').val() != '') {
            $('#ppm').attr('disabled', true);
            calculatePPM(); 
        } else {
            $('#ppm').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });

    $('input#mol').keyup(function(){
        if( $('#mgm3').prop('disabled') ) {
            calculateMGM3();
        }
        if( $('#ppm').prop('disabled') ) {
            calculatePPM();
        }   
    });

    function calculateMGM3() {
        var mol = parseFloat($('#mol').val());
        var ppm = parseFloat($('#ppm').val());
        var calcMGM3 = parseFloat(( ppm * mol ) / 24.45 ).toFixed(2);
        $('#mgm3').val( calcMGM3 );
    }

    function calculatePPM() {
        var mol = parseFloat($('#mol').val());
        var mgm3 = parseFloat($('#mgm3').val());
        var calcPPM = parseFloat(( mgm3 * 24.45 ) / mol ).toFixed(2);
        $('#ppm').val( calcPPM );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a fair few errors in your code

- `calculateXX` functions were inside the event handler - don't need to be, moved outside
- When calling a method you need parentheses, so changed `$(this).calculatePPM` to simply `calculatePPM()` (no idea why you had `$(this)` in front.
- Added `parseFloat` to where you're readng numeric values from text fields.
- You were using aliased variables like `$ppm` but these were not declared anywhere. It is actually good practice to not keep using jQuery selectors, and to cache references to fields in a variable. But to keep the change minimal I have not done this. I suggest you do though.

```js
// formula for ppm =    mg/m3 * 24.45 / mol
// formula for mg/m3 =  ppm * mol / 24.45
 
 
 $('input.value').keyup(function(){
    var ppm = $('#ppm');
    var mgm3 = $('#mgm3');
    var mol = $('#mol');

    if( $('#ppm').val() != '') {
        $('#mgm3').attr('disabled', true);

        calculateMGM3();
    } else {
        $('#mgm3').attr('disabled', false);
    }

    if( $('#mgm3').val() != '') {
        $('#ppm').attr('disabled', true);

        calculatePPM(); 
    } else {
        $('#ppm').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});



function calculateMGM3() {
    var mol = parseFloat($('#mol').val());
    var ppm = parseFloat($('#ppm').val());
    var calcMGM3 = (( ppm * mol ) / 24.45 );
    $('#mgm3').val( calcMGM3 );
}

function calculatePPM() {
    var mol = parseFloat($('#mol').val());
    var mgm3 = parseFloat($('#mgm3').val());
    var calcPPM = (( mgm3 * 24.45 ) / mol );
    $('#ppm').val( calcPPM );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="calc">
    <h1>MG/M³ - PPM Calculator</h1>
    <div class="gfield">
        <label>PPM</label>
        <input class="value" type="number" name="ppm" id="ppm">
    </div>
    <div class="gfield">
        <label>MG/M³</label>
        <input class="value" type="number" name="mgm3" id="mgm3">
    </div>
    <div class="gfield">
        <label>Molmassa</label>
        <input class="value" type="number" name="mol" id="mol">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I would add `.toFixed(2)` (or 3) to set the decimal amount to something reasonnable...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yes I agree, I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP :)

Comment: I'll appreciate your suggestions and fixes. Will fix it and post the updated version